# Rails can't run：`require': incompatible library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I use rvm for ruby version management,
but rails can't run when I execute 'rails s'.
I reinstall rvm,and I also reinstall gems still problem.
I'm desperate and need your help!
console log:

`` /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle (fatal)
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
    from /Users/brucewzp/develop/rubydev/lofi/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brucewzp/develop/rubydev/lofi/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/brucewzp/develop/rubydev/lofi/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/brucewzp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/brucewzp/develop/rubydev/lofi/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /Users/brucewzp/develop/rubydev/lofi/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>' ``

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with mysql2 gem. Try `gem uninstall mysql2` (all versions) and then `bundle install`

Comment: @PetrGazarov I tried but not work

Comment: try this `gem pristine --all`

Comment: @PardeepSaini not work

Comment: did you install mysql2 gem and mysql properly and also required libraries.

Comment: Have you notice some error/warning messages during **bundle install**?

Comment: @EddeAlmeida 'bundle install' seems work fine

Comment: Then remove your **Gemfile.lock** and run **bundle install** again, now observing the moment when mysql2 gem is installed. If you still have problems after this, post here the error you'll probably see during mysql2 installation.

Comment: @PardeepSaini I installed mysql using homebrew,and I tried 'rails new project' and  still wrong with 'incompatible library version '

Comment: @EddeAlmeida thanks for your advice.but it still doesn't work,and I tried setup a new project,but same error **incompatible library version**,and it happened with gem 'debug_inspector-0.0.2'.

Comment: can you write down the steps you use to install rvm and rails ?

Comment: @PardeepSaini my step unsintall rvm:1. rvm implode 2. rm -rf ~/.rvm 3. gem cleanup --force

Comment: Install rvm refering http://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: Here is another suggestion: **1)** Enter your app directory and run **rvm use ruby-2.3.0@your_app_name_here --ruby-version --create**. This will generate a bundle for your app, apart from the global bundle you are using now; **2)** Run **gem install bundler**; **3)** Run **bundle install**; Then try to run your app again.

Comment: Try 'brew uninstall mysql2'

Comment: Is the behaviour the same if you execute `bundle exec rails s`?

Comment: @All thank you for all your help,Gemset is not comparable,I use global gemset by 'rvm gemset use global' solved problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try: 
gem pristine --all